# Is a for loop in a parameter allowed?

Tags: parameters

I am wondering if there is any condition in any programming language that would allow a "for" loop in a function parameter?

My code:

```
public void function(int number,for(int b;b>number;b++){int param2, int param3,int param4,int param5,int param6})
{                      //start of body
for(int b;b>number;b++)
{
object[b].setter(param2)
object[b].setter(param3)
object[b].setter(param4)
object[b].setter(param5)
object[b].setter(param6)
}
}
```

This way the 2nd+ parameters of the function would have to be entered the number of times that is specified in the 1st parameter.

If this is not allowed,what would you recommend me to do instead?

And still,this is very messy coding, so what should I do instead?

Answer (score 1):

In C, there are two straightforward ways to do this.
One is to pass two parameters: `number`, and a pointer to an int array of length `6*number` holding all the other arguments (alternatively: six pointers to arrays of length `number` each). This would typically require some manual preparation of the arguments before the call.
The other way would be to use a variadic function. This would make the call sites simpler, but pretty much every call site would have to know at compile time how many arguments it's passing in (barring macro shenanigans).

In most more modern mainstream languages, the idiomatic thing to do would be to pass in a reference to a "list"-type collection (or, again, six references to collections). You wouldn't even need the `number` param, as the collections can answer the question "how many members do you have".

I'm sure in some more fringe languages you could just define a function that just keeps taking arguments as long as there are any.